# Facebook feed dialogue not showing custom image and custom caption on opened dialogue

Tags: facebook, feed

I am throughly checking documenations & some articles in web.but i am unable to share custome feed in facebook.The feed was opening but it was not showing custom params even i am sending paramas like link, image, caption etc.Please help me.

Comment: <script>
//Function displays the Feed Dialog
function LaunchFeedDialog() {
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://fbrell.com/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',    
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post. success');
     } else {
       alert('Post fail.');
     }
   }
 );
}   
</script>

Comment: This has been removed with API v2.9, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe mentioned, custom parameters (caption, description etc) are deprecated

You need to use Open Graph tags (og:image, og_description etc) on the shared page (if you own the page).

See http://ogp.me/ for more info about Open Graph

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue: we published our latest WordPress plugin and found the feed dialog wasn't working. So we found an alternative method to achieve the feed dialogue module with custom parameters.

**Alternative 1:** To use an existing jQuery or WordPress plugin to expedite the process of development. https://codecanyon.net/item/smartview-wordpress/20505173 We're thinking of releasing a free much simpler version for both WordPress and jQuery.

**Alternative 2:** Creating a catch all page titled "sharer.php" with a function to grab each post's variables to plug into the open graph metadata. Of course, you'll want to add conditional statements to verify the source format.